Display Complete pandas after search query
i want  to implement following very small project, namely user should enter  name  of product  and python should search in database and  show  result of query in pyqt6  deksptop application ,  for  this  i have  implemented following basic  GUI form :

here user enters product,  then clicks on button and result will be  displayed on empty space, which is :QTextEdit(), most interesting part is this function :
def return_product_info(self):
        input_text =self.inputField.text()
        
        df = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * FROM "foreign_products" where "product" = '{}'
        '''.format( input_text), con=engine)
        print(df.head())
        self.output.setText(df)

engine part is hidden (it works fine), only interesting part is this :
 self.output.setText(df)

how  can i put  df in  QTextEdit()? i have  done a little research and found  out that  i can use  QTableView  based on this link  :
QTableView
but how can i  connect  all this into one project? here is main code for the  app
class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Database Search")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("db.jpg"))
        self.resize(500,500)
        layout =QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.inputField =QLineEdit()
        self.button =QPushButton("click me")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.return_product_info)
        self.output =QTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.inputField)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.output)

result what i want to see is this :

this is shown on console , but i want  in text  editor below  button ("click me"), please help me how to  do it

QTextEdit "set text" functions only accept strings, and Pandas data frames are not. Did you try a simple self.output.setText(str(df))?

@musicamante that is exactly when  here question asker is looking for professional person, thanks a lot, can i control spaces with this format?
